# Django objects.get(): The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to check if a user exists in the database based on email address, so I get the email and if that email exists, I want to return the username of that user alongside with some other data.

I'm using objects.get() method to do so but I keep getting this error.

Did some search on it, a couple of solutions were suggesting to do a filter and return the .first() object or instead of email=email, suggested to put email=email[0], but both of these approaches ended up giving me an empty array in response.

Here's my Views.py:

```
class CheckEmailView(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = CheckEmailSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    email = Account.objects.filter(email=serializer.data['email'])
    if email.exists():
        username = Account.objects.get(email=email)
        return Response({'is_member': True, 'username': username})
    else:
        return Response({'is_member': False})
```

Comment: Why are you doing two queries to `Account`? Is your filter returning results? If so you can just use the `QuerySet` under `email`

Comment: @PacketLoss first query returns if the email exists and the second one is meant to return the username of the existing user but instead throws that error. and the filter is returning results yes. but I don't know how to use the QuerySet under email to get the username. can you elaborate?

Comment: Try adding `.first()` to the end of your filter, then `print(email.username)`

Comment: @PacketLoss IT WORKED. Thank you so much 

Comment: Great! I have added the comment as an answer. If it helped feel free to accept the answer so it may assist others in the future. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do two queries to `Account` when you want to access other columns in the same data set.

Simply call the field you want from the initial filter.

It should be noted that filters can return multiple rows if they exist, if you want to ensure only the first is returned add `.first()` to your filter.

Now you can call the following to return the username.

```
email.username
```